# How to have a glossary entry as part of a lettrine?

Tags: macros, glossaries, lettrine

My MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
   nopostdot,
   acronym,
   nonumberlist,
   nomain,
   sort=def,
   nostyles,
   translate=babel,
 ]{glossaries}

 \usepackage{lettrine} 
 \LettrineTextFont{\itshape}
 \setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
 \renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\normalfont}
 \renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\normalfont}

 %---- glossaries
 \newglossaryentry{MM}{%
    type=\acronymtype, 
    name={MM}, 
    first={Mickey Mouse (following MM)},
   }
 \newcommand\MM{\gls{MM}}

\begin{document}
  \lettrine{M}{ickey} Mouse (following MM);  \MM\\[5em]
  \glsresetall
  \lettrine{\MM}{}
\end{document}
```

The result is this:
[image]

---

How can I have the macro `\MM` in the `\lettrine`-command, so it will be the first appearance of the name. 
Or is there a way to omit the `first`-option (`Mickey Mouse (following MM)`) so I could write it manually as below?

Comment: Theres a neat glossary command that can be used to create a manual use that will also expand contextually:  `\glsdisp{label}{custom use}`.  Using lettrine inside expands, it's just not as automatic as one might want.

Comment: works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [EngBIRD](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/69378/engbird) said, the key is `\glsdisp{label}{custom use}`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
   nopostdot,
   acronym,
   nonumberlist,
   nomain,
   sort=def,
   nostyles,
   translate=babel,
 ]{glossaries}

 \usepackage{lettrine} 
 \LettrineTextFont{\itshape}
 \setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
 \renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\normalfont}
 \renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\normalfont}

 %---- glossaries
 \newglossaryentry{MM}{%
    type=\acronymtype, 
    name={MM},
    description={comic figure},
    first={Mickey Mouse (following MM)},
   }
 \newcommand\MM{\gls{MM}}

\begin{document}
  \lettrine{M}{ickey} Mouse (following MM);  \MM\\[5em]
  \glsresetall
  \glsdisp{MM}{\lettrine{M}{ickey} Mouse (following MM)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. I wasn't sure if you were looking for a way to automatically detect if you were in a first line, and hence, automatic lettrine usage situation. That was a fair bit above my ability to help with.